# Is there any power mode selection feature for nvidia gpu?

Tags: cuda

Is there any power mode selection feature for nvidia gpu? for example, normal, high performance, or power save mode? If so, is it possible to select a power mode when I compile my cuda program by nvcc? And is it possible to check current power mode status of my gpu?

Actually I could not find any clue of this, though have searched a little long time from web.

Comment: "select a power mode when I compile my cuda program by nvcc"... why would you need to do that? Your GPU has nothing to do with NVCC compilation.

Comment: I just want to run my cuda program with the highest performance mode if I can do it. In other words, I'm just worrying about that my cuda program is running on a power save mode or not good performance mode without my knowledge.

Comment: Ah, I misread that as "I want my GPU to run at full power when compiling with NVCC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your GPU you may be able to use nvidia-smi or NVML (check out the [documentation](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation) for more information) to read the current power state, the GPU will dynamically change the power state to conserve power when idle and to provide performance when under load.

As a user it is not possible to set the power state of the GPU - the Tesla product line does have power-capping for the server products but that's not under user control obviously.